# undefined is not a function (near '...}).finally(function () {...') in react native

Tags: react-native

Undefined returns on promise. Finally block is not defined. How to resolve this?

> undefined is not a function (near '...}).finally(function () {...')
>   run
>       internet_connection_checking_timer.ts:34:21 handleAppWentToForeground
>       index.tsx:46:8 handleAppStateChange
>       index.tsx:36:16 
>       AppState.js:89:18 emit
>       EventEmitter.js:191:12
>   __callFunction
>       MessageQueue.js:366:47 
>       MessageQueue.js:106:26
>   __guard
>       MessageQueue.js:314:10 callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
>       MessageQueue.js:105:17 callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
>       [native code]

```
EventAPIService.getxx()
            .then(responseModel => {

            })
            //.catch(()=>console.log("error"))
            .finally(() => {// returns error if I use finally
                if (loadingShowed) {
                    this.setState({loading: false});
                }
            });
```

Comment: please provide code snippet.

Comment: ok please check